# standard visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, removal

I voluntarily left the UK in 2008, with a view to lodging an entry clearance application to re-enter the United Kingdom as a person exercising rights of access to a child resident in the UK.

Now, I'm completing the UK standard visit visa form. There is a question:

**Have you subjected to an exclusion order from UK?**

What should my answer should be?

I left the UK willingly. I went to the Border and Immigration Agency office near me and told them I wanted to go home. We agreed that I would buy my own flight ticket, which I did, but I asked for time to prepare my 5-year-old daughter that I was leaving for quite some time.

During my requested 3 months, I was given a notification of temporary admission to a person who is liable to be detained and instructed to report to the Immigration Office at the point of departure with the details of my flight date and time. I complied with those conditions.

Comment: The standard visit visa form asks if you have been "required to leave." Were you asked to leave or put under an obligation to go?

Comment: i went to Border and immigration agency office near me and told them i want to go home we agree that i will buy my own flight ticket which i did.but i ask them to give me atleast three month to prepare my 5 years old daughter that,dad is going back to his home country for sometime.During my requested 3 months of staying waiting for my trip  i was given a letter say notification of temporary admission to a person who is liable to be detained."instruct to report to the immigration office at the point of departure with the details of my flight date and time

Comment: Please provide us with a scan of your notification of temporary admission, with personal details blacked out. Thank you.